# Loading CSV file under windows does not work with chyper and Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I use NEO4J 3.2.3. I wanted to import a local csv file into my neo4j under Windows.
I used the documentation on the official site and just replaced the file path to my case. My chyper looks like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/Users/NP-
900XC/Documents/Business/BooknWalk/neo4jimportBnw/bookdomain.csv"
AS line
WITH line LIMIT 4
RETURN line
```

According to the documentation this query just shows how chyper recognizes the csv file.
I got the following error:
`Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError URI is not hierarchical`
The developers manual also says that the file path should be relative to Neo4J's import library. The small problem is that I do not have import library.
What do I make wrong?

Comment: Put your bookdomain.csv in C:\Users\NP-
900XC\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\import and LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/bookdomain.csv"

Comment: Then remove the EXE install and start working with the ZIP install. You'll find it's a lot easier to find the directories :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**, allow Neo4j to load CSV from everywhere on your disk.

1. Open the Launcher, stop the server, click on Options and open the **neo4j.config** file (under the "Database Options" label).
2. Comment the line `dbms.directories.import=import` (put a `#` before it).
3. Save and **restart** Neo4j server. (Or, *to be sure*, close it enterely and then restart it)

You are using a **wrong path** in `LOAD CSV`.

**Try with the following**:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/Users/NP-
900XC/Documents/Business/BooknWalk/neo4jimportBnw/bookdomain.csv"
```

As you can see, the key difference is "`///`".

There is nothing wrong with the "exe" installation method; just set-up Neo4j correctly and it will load from any dir on your Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks @Sergio it worked. I do not understand why the documentation says: Make sure to use the right URLs. In particular for file URLs: On OSX and Unix use file:///path/to/data.csv, and on Windows use a URL similar to: file:c:/path/to/data.csv. I use windows

Comment: Glad it worked. Maybe the docs are a bit old, I don't really know.